# CakePHP find on a join table

Tags: cakephp

Sorry if this is obvious - I'm trying to do a find() on a join table and failing, whats the correct syntax to do this?

Basically I have expenseCode table with a HABTM releationship with the expense table.

In my expenseCode model I have:

```
public function beforeDelete($cascade  = false) {

    $count = $this->Expense->find("count", array(
        'conditions' => array('expense_code_id' => $this->id)
    ));

    if ($count == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        //$this->Session->setFlash('Record cannot be deleted as it has ' . $count . 'number of expenses attached to it');
        return false;
    }

}
```

If I uncomment the setFlash() I get the error.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So should there be no expense_code_ids matching this->id ?
the syntax looks correct, and the find is working but is finding at least one result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to perform such a query on the HABTM join table from one of the parent models without some extra work. I'm assuming that Expense is the parent model and ExpensesCode the join model?

A common way is to modelise the HABTM join table. Say you have an `expenses` and `codes` table which are joined by `expenses_codes`:

```
$this->Expense->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('ExpensesCode')));
$this->Expense->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array('Expense.*'),
  'conditions' => array('ExpensesCode.expense_code_id' => $this->id)
));
```

However, Cake also auto-iniatlises a model for the join table when a HABTM association is defined (see [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm), and the **"with"** key in the list of possible keys).

So this syntax would let you directly query the join table:

```
$this->Expense->ExpensesCode->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array('ExpensesCode.expense_code_id' => $this->id)
));
```

The query above will net you with an array containing only the results from the join table, as it doesn't perform a join like the first procedure. So you would have to perform a second `find()` on the Expense model to find the expenses related to the `expense_code_id` from ExpensesCode.

**EDIT:**
It's a framework convention that HABTM join tables should be underscored and alphabetically ordered. So if the HABTM join table is called `codes_expenses`, it's auto-modelised as `CodesExpense`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, will test it out now.

Comment: Just realised that the convention for HABTM tables is to have them in alphabetical order. So if your join table is called `codes_expenses` and auto-modelised as CodesExpense by CakePHP.

Comment: Hi, my table names are - expenses, expense_codes and expenses_expense_codes (the join table). I'm wanting this check to go into the Expense_code model (so if your trying to delete a expense code with expenses using it, you get an error). So I'm guessing my find query would be - $this->ExpenseCode->Expense->find...?? Thanks again

Comment: Ah, found it - $count = $this->Expense->ExpensesExpenseCode->find("count", array( - thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also work in a simpler way if you create another model with two hasMany relations instead of one with HABTM.

> HasAndBelongsToMany between two models is in reality shorthand for three models associated through both a hasMany and a belongsTo association.

I found it is one of the simplest ways to save and retrieve data.

For more information:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#what-to-do-when-habtm-becomes-complicated